# IOS: Files are failed to import in Current Project, Shows error "File not found"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

[image]

in my project every time i tried to import any file to my project it always shows an error "file not found" while the file is present in the bundle
how to remove this error

Comment: Why is this question posted twice under two different account? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836228/ios-files-failed-to-import-in-current-project-shows-error-file-not-found

Comment: why given the upvote for this question, this type of question already discussed many times in stack overflow

Comment: Restart Xcode and iMac both.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

- Go to the target => Go the the "Build Phases" => Expand the "Compile Sources"
  delete the [filename that cause the error].m => Add the file back.
- Product => Clean

Answer (score 0):

Once delete(remove reference) the group and create group or add individually classes in the project. This resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove Reference of your file and manually add files in your project.Do not Direct Import in Project. Just Copy File in your Project Folder and manually add File.
This may be help you.